# Replacing the last character in a string javascript

Tags: javascript

How do we replace last character of a string?

```
SetCookie('pre_checkbox', "111111111111 11   ")
    checkbox_data1 = GetCookie('pre_checkbox');

    if(checkbox_data1[checkbox_data1.length-1]==" "){
         checkbox_data1[checkbox_data1.length-1]= '1';
         console.log(checkbox_data1+"after");

    }

out put on console : 111111111111 11   after
```

Last character was not replaced by '1' dont know why

also tried : `checkbox_data1=checkbox_data1.replace(checkbox_data1.charAt(checkbox_data1.length-1), "1");`

could some one pls help me out

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: immutable only means a new memory location is allocated for a changed string. Doesnt mean you cannot change a string.

Comment: @SujeshArukil: "Doesnt mean you cannot change a string"...?  That is *precisely* what immutable means.  You can assign a *different* string, but you can't change the original.  And JS won't do the reassignment for you except in certain cases (like `str += something`), as pass-by-value languages like JS won't let the callee just up and change the caller's variables.

Comment: Yes, you cannot change the original, thus that is why you must set the return of the action on the original to the (same) variable name to which you want the new value set.

Comment: that is correct. All I meant was, the op wants to replace a character. What you get back would be a new string, not the modified original string. The original string cannot be updated, but a new string with the value replaced can be created.

Comment: @SujeshArukil: If you call a function that does the replacement and returns you a new string, or use `+` to create a string with additional chars, then yes.  You can assign it to the variable/property that held the original, and it looks changed.  But for example, `str[0] = 'x'` will not work; it just silently fails, as a string's indexes are not writable.  It has to be done another way.

Comment: Thats correct. Agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple regex replace should do what you want:

```
checkbox_data1 = checkbox_data1.replace(/.$/,1);
```

Generic version:

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/.$/,"replacement");
```

Remember that just calling `str.replace()` doesn't apply the change to `str` unless you do `str = str.replace()` - that is, apply the `replace()` function's return value back to the variable `str`

Comment: Just to be clear: It's not the regexp that solves the problem, but the assignment of the `replace`'s return value to the original variable name.

Comment: @RobW Yes, I have clarified that fact with a final sentence

Comment: @SmokeyPHP ..just an extension to this question ..... say if i want to replace a space which is in the middle say at 3rd position for example : "ab c d" ...how do we do that ?

Comment: @user2569524 `str = str.replace(/^(..)./,'$1'+'replacement')` if the third is to be replaced -- `^` is the start of the string, `.` means any character, and the `$1` is putting back into the string the 2 characters matched in `(..)`

Comment: @user2569524 Sorry just noticed you specified a space, previous code should be `str = str.replace(/^(..) /,'$1'+'replacement')`

Answer (score 1):

use regex...

```
var checkbox_data1 = '111111111111 11   ';
checkbox_data1.replace(/ $/,'$1');
console.log(checkbox_data1);
```

This will replace the last space in the string.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob said, strings are immutable. Ex:

```
var str = "abc";
str[0] = "d";
console.log(str); // "abc" not "dbc"
```

You could do:

```
var str = "111 ";
str = str.substr(0, str.length-1) + "1"; // this makes a _new_ string
```

Comment: Note, IE doesn't support negative numbers with `substr`.  `str.substr(0, -1)` gives me `""`.  (Plus, `substr` isn't defined by ECMAScript anyway; it's just a common addition.  If you're going to start at 0, then `substring` does the same thing and is standardized.)

Answer (score 0):

This is also a way, without regexp :)

```
var string = '111111111111 11   ';
var tempstr = '';
if (string[string.length - 1] === ' ') {
    for (i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i += 1) {
        tempstr += string[i];
    }
    tempstr += '1';
}
```

Comment: What is your intention? `abcdefghdesiredValues` is not the desired result.

Comment: I guess he can get the desired result out from the current code.

Comment: On console.log it appears (string - 1) + '1'. I don't know what you mean by string+'1'. You can log this code and see the result.

Comment: Why would you bother tacking on each character like this, when you could just say `str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1) + '1'`?  Read about [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have some space in our string please try it

```
checkbox_data1=checkbox_data1.replace(checkbox_data1.charAt(checkbox_data1.length-4), "1   ");
```

then add the space in

```
console.log(checkbox_data1+"   after");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var checkbox_data1=checkbox_data1.replace(checkbox_data1.slice(-1),"+");
```

This will replace the last character of Your string with "+".

Comment: Not quite.  It'll replace *the first instance* of the string's last character.  If the string is `'11111111 111   '`, the *first* space (that is, the 9th character in the string) is what will get replaced.